# MongoDB create compund index text and NumberLong with spring-boot annotation

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, spring-annotations

please look this mongodb index:

```
{
    "v" : 2,
    "key" : {
        "_fts" : "text",
        "_ftsx" : 1,
        "time_in_millisecond" : -1.0
    },
    "name" : "field_1_text_time_in_millisecond_-1",
    "weights" : {
        "field_1" : 1
    },
    "default_language" : "none",
    "language_override" : "dummy",
    "textIndexVersion" : 3
},
```

I would like to create it using the spring-boot annotation, anyone have any suggestions about it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
@Document(collection = "your_collection")
@CompoundIndex(name = "field_1_text_time_in_millisecond_-1", def = "{'_fts' : 'text', '_ftsx': 1, 'time_in_millisecond': -1}")
public class SomeClass {...}
```

[CompoundIndex](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/index/CompoundIndex.html)